# What does "git checkout dev" mean?

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a project and the instructions state:

```
Get the latest changes from the dev branch:

git checkout dev

git fetch && git pull
```

What exactly am I supposed to do? Where do I enter these? Please help.

Comment: It tells _git_ to perform a _checkout_ (download) on the _dev_ branch of the current folder’s remote code repository. You’ll probably need to get the github cloning url, so _git_ knows where to find/get the _dev_ branch.

Comment: Just to add on to @Adam Smooch, Enter these in your command prompt of the cloned folder. If you’re uncomfortable with git commands using something like GitDesktop might help.

Comment: @adam-smooch Hey thanks for the answer. So I downloaded the zip of the project from github and typed "git checkout dev" it says "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

Comment: @Jason hey so I  ran a command prompt and entered "git checkout dev" it says "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git" can you help pls

Comment: If you downloaded the code, unzip it and you can probably skip all the *git* commands, as these will probably only serve to fetch the code you’ve downloaded manually.

Comment: @AdamSmooch Oh I see thanks. So if I want to get the updates for the project how do I do this? You said "get the github cloning url" I have the url but what do I do with it.

Comment: 3 options: Download a zip (of the dev branch) and replace the old unzipped folder, clone the repo with (e.g.) GitDesktop, or learn to do so with git and use the commands in your original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit, that you added later in a comment, is missing from your question:

> So I downloaded the zip of the project from github ...

If you use GitHub's "download a zip file" clicky web button, you do not get a *repository*.  You cannot run `git` operations on the result as it is not a repository.  You just get one commit *from* the repository.

Whether the project you're using can be used in this way depends on the project you're using.  If it *can* be used this way, get a zip file of the commit that is the latest commit on the `dev` branch.

If this project can't be used this way, don't use GitHub's "download a zip file" button.  Instead, get the repository URL and use `git clone` on the command line, in your command line interpreter, likely in a Terminal window, on your computer:

```
$ cd projects
$ git clone <url>
$ cd this-project
```

assuming the GitHub URL was something like `ssh://git@github.com/user/projects/this-project.git`, for instance.

in a bash-like shell on a Linux-like system, for instance.

Comment: This solved it thank you.